# ng-serve load too slowly

Tags: angular

I am using Angular version 8, while execute ng-serve command to start the project it takes too long time around 20-25 minutes on my machine, same code while execute in other machine it is running quickly.
What is the problem in my machine..

Comment: Can you post more details? What does 'your machine' mean? OS, version, node version, hardware etc... What are the details of the 'other machine'?

Comment: My machine meaning here is "my laptop" and i am using node 10.15.1 and windows OS.

Comment: That's still not enough information, but I can only guess that you do not have enough internal memory (only 2 or 4GB), and that you have a normal HDD in your laptop on which the paging memory is used, which will result in very slow read/writes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try upgrading Node to v12. It's recommended for Angular v8. It gave my machine a bit of boost for the same issue.

Regarding your system config, the min RAM should be 8+ gb and use a SSD for faster disk I/O.

Comment: Thanks, after upgrading node version, it is execcuting in 2-3 minutes.